# Looking for the right word - expelling pills from a canister

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary

I would appreciate if someone could teach me the appropriate word for what I am trying to say.

1. It must be a verb
2. The meaning is the action that happens when for example a pill or tablet is expelled from a canister automatically from a machine

---

Please don't read below this before thinking of a word. (I don't want to influence or interfere your train of thoughts). I am thinking of the word

> "dispense"

<sup>(mouse over box to see word)</sup>

but I am not sure if it is correct. I would be happy for other alternatives.

Comment: The word you've guessed is probably the best word there is.

Comment: Actually for me, looking at a word stimulates my thinking, which can be contrarian.

Answer (score 3):

As @J.R. mentions, ***dispense*** is likely the best choice. ***Dispense*** has specific meanings for both machines and medication:

> *of a machine or container:* to supply or release (a product or cash)
>
> *of a chemist:* to make up and give out (medicine) according to a doctor's prescription.
>
> (Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dispense)

In fact, a ***dispensary*** is "a place where medicine or dental treatment is dispensed." (Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispensary)

Looking at the synonyms for ***dispense***, I don't see any great alternative you can use. You might be able to use ***disburse*** or ***allocate***, but they imply actions that a human would take, not a machine.

I suppose you could call a machine that dispenses pills a "pill allocator," but it wouldn't be nearly as good as "pill dispenser." "Pill allocator" *might* be more appropriate if you have a large number and/or wide variety of pills.

Comment: Emmmmm... .. PEZ