# Looking for the right word - feeding pills into a tray

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary

I am again looking for the right word to use for a technical document. 
I would like to find a word that

1. is a verb (or a ing-verb "eating" "drinking")
2. It describes the following action: Say I have a tray-like mechanism with compartments and I put a number of pills into each of these compartments by hand.

I have been finding words like "shedding", "sprinkle" but I am not quite convinced that they are right for what I want to express.

EDIT: Additional

How about "**feeding**" pills to the tray?

EDIT2
This is a related to my [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145009/looking-for-the-right-word-expelling-pills-from-a-canister)

Comment: *Dispensing*, perhaps?

Comment: Umm I am using "dispensing" for when a pill is being expelled automatically from a canister.. In this case, instead, I am feeding the machine with pills (to be dispensed later)

Comment: How about distributing?

Comment: I would suggest including a link to your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145009/looking-for-the-right-word-expelling-pills-from-a-canister) to provide more context. Not everyone reading this will be familiar with your previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, a simple *loading* might do here. Or you could go with *manually loading* to encompass the "by hand" aspect.

Feeding, as you've suggested, would be another great fit for this case. It can also be used with manually in order to make it clear that this step is to be done by hand.

> **feed (verb):** supply (a machine) with material, power, or other things necessary for its operation.

Another option that might work is priming.

> **prime (verb):** make (something) ready for use or action, in particular.

Comment: Or *[stocking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stock#Verb)*, since one is establishing a stock of product to be dispensed later.

Comment: How about "feeding"?  (Although stocking seems really nice too)

Comment: @KansaiRobot Yes, feeding would be a good option, too. It can also be combined with the adverb manually to make it clear that the process is to be done by hand. So you could say something like "In order to prepare (or stock, using Chemomechanics suggestion) the device for a processing batch, you must first fill the tray by manually feeding twelve pills into each compartment."

Comment: *Feeding* suggests that the machine will in some way be running on the pills. Stocking, loading, filling.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Sure, feeding a fire, or feeding power (electricity) to a machine carries that connotation. But manually feeding paper into a printer doesn't power the printer. A gravity fed paint sprayer runs on external pressure; the gravity only causes paint to be fed into the sprayer mechanism. In this case, the operator is manually feeding pills into the machine so that it may dispense them. [see also](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feed+into)

Comment: Running on or consuming/using (as a printer does paper). From the question it wasn't clear to me that this is a dispensing machine as opposed to an organizer tray, which you can't feed.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Okay - it was clarified in a comment, but not in the question itself. KansaiRobot had also asked another question recently regarding this same technical document, so I had a little more context in responding to the question. I just left a comment suggesting that it be included in this question.